# Having a trained classifier like VGG16 how to automate image segmentation?

Tags: automation, neural-network, classification, image-segmentation

I Have a trained classifier: VGG16 on say Image Net (or my own images DB and classes). I want to segment my images automatically knowing there are classes on images my classifier knows. How to automate image segmentation?

Comment: How you will segment images Using `VGG16`? Isn't a classifier?

Comment: @ashraful16: That's the point - we have only a classifier and want to generate segmentation maps (not having segmentation data for training)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can extract [Grad-CAM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391) features. `Kears` already has published an official documentation for `Grad-CAM extraction` you can find it [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/).
So for your task steps need to followed are

1. `Extract Grad-CAM from the images`
2. `Based on Grad-CAM create a  segmentation mask using simple image processing technique`

In this method `you can easily create segmentation mask for images` but masks `may not be so accurate` . Beacuse, see this picture,

[image]

it is for `Xception model (ImageNet).`

Hope you will understand and you will be helpful.